# How to add a div into the top right corner of a textarea, and have the text start after the div (pic inside)

Tags: html, css

So the user can type a command that activates a "reply"-mode. How can I have a badge/div/label/etc in the top left corner of the textarea that the user's text starts after.

Here is a terrible representation if what I want to acheive (this is absolutely positioned, and the text has a bunch of spaces, so not a real solution, just for an example.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the overlay div's width is not fixed, a little more Javascript will do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    var $overlay = $('#widget #overlay'),
        $textarea = $('#widget textarea')
    ;
    $textarea.css({
        textIndent: $overlay.width() + 'px'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="overlay">Replying to @jimc sac as cas cac </div>
        <textarea class="form-control">Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#widget{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#widget #overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#widget textarea{
    border: none;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

The codepen: http://codepen.io/duonglk/pen/PGYdOp (with Bootstrap loaded for nice UI)

Comment: This is really close to what I want. Only issue is when the user types past the textarea height, the text scrolls under the div, I'll have to fix it with JS

Answer (score 0):

Used CSS [text-inden](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp) Property in textarea

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.inside{
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
}
textarea 
{
  text-indent: 150px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<label class="inside">
  X replying to @abc
</label >
 <textarea rows="5" html="true" id="text" >Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely positioned label and `text-indent` on the `textarea`

```css
textarea {

  text-indent: 150px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 145px;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="">Your thing here</label>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem itaque dolore architecto cum, fuga excepturi, natus necessitatibus facere ipsum minima voluptas provident laudantium eum maiores rerum? Perspiciatis fugiat vel sapiente quod quasi quia modi ab consequuntur eaque nulla facere, possimus illum ducimus, rerum minima harum eligendi incidunt repellendus obcaecati, sit.</textarea>
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <textarea style="height:150px; width:200px; text-indent: 85px">
  </textarea>
  <div style="position:absolute; height:20px; width:80px; background-color:gray; top:0px"></div>
</div>
```

In addition please note to: `text-indent: 85px` in order to start the first line after the div

Answer (score -3):

A made code for You:

You only have to use `float`

```css
.container{
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
}

.inside{
  background-color:red;
  width:60px;
  height:10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inside">

</div>
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</div>
```

Comment: A div is not a `textarea.`